# LINQ: compare 2 table return non duplicate row

Tags: linq

table 1 
ID
1
3

table 2
ID, name 
1  a
2  b
3  c

how can we write a linq to return a table with only
2 b
should compare both tables and return the first row

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like:

```
var query = table2.Where(data => !table1.Select(x => x.ID).Contains(data.ID));
```

Or to get the first such row:

```
var first = table2.Where(data => !table1.Select(x => x.ID).Contains(data.ID))
                  .First();
```

Note that that would be relatively slow in LINQ to Objects - you'd want:

```
HashSet<int> ids = new HashSet<int>(table1.Select(x => x.ID));
var query = table2.Where(data => !ids.Contains(data.ID));
```

The first should be fine in something like LINQ to SQL though.

Comment: I give up. I was writing about the same thing, but it is difficult to beat Jon Skeet ;) You got my vote at least..

Comment: HashSet<int> ids = new HashSet<int>(table1.Select(x => x.ID));
var query = table2.Where(data => !ids.Contains(data.ID)); give error new x.ID

Comment: @linqbeta: That suggests that the type in `table1` doesn't have an ID property, or it's not an `int`. Give more details in the question, and I'm more likely to be able to give an answer which compiles... please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints (Also, give a more precise error message...)

Comment: these are 2 datatables, 1st with field [id] and 2nd fields[id, name]

Comment: @linqbeta: Do you mean they're plain `DataTable`? If so, you'll want to use `Field<int>`. I don't think there's much point in me editing my answer until you've made the question clearer though, with sample code.

Comment: Right they're plain DataTable. Changed to HashSet<string> ids = new HashSet<string>(dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("ID")));
                    var query = dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(data => !ids.Contains(data.Field<string>("ID")));
Returns - Enumeration yielded no results

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the question - but normaly you will do something like

```
            var t1 = new[] {1, 2, 3};
            var t2 = new[] {1, 4, 3};
            var res = t2.Where(x => !t1.Contains(x));
```